# Warning: No 'initWithPrimaryKey". method found

Tags: iphone

I'm getting the following warning in this statement:

> Warning: No 'initWithPrimaryKey". method found

```
HoldingArray *holdObj=[[HoldingArray alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:n];
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: you might considering accepting some answers if they were helpful

Answer (score 1):

The error should be clear: The class `HoldingArray` doesn't expose a method `initWithPrimaryKey`.

Refer to the source code of the class `HoldingArray` or the documentation which methods are available.